# Agile/Scrum project management like Jira but simpeler

Tags: open-source, saas

I am looking for a Jira software like solution but simpler. I tried configuring Jira to my needs. Just showing story points in the backlog is a task which needs research and is not straightforward. And to be honest it seems like the software is too advanced for my needs (right now). Since very simple things take a lot of time to find and configure.

I looked into different packages. And there seems to be 1 key feature which I need which is often missing.

- I need the software to be **able to make a sprint which consists of stories from multiple projects**. I'd like to use it for clients who don't fill up an entire sprint on their own. Instead we combine multiple clients into 1 sprint. But their projects must be separated of course. Jira makes this possible with a global board.
- An open-source hosted versions or SaaS are both fine. As long as the pricing is ok, preferable free. Jira is free up to 10 users, which is ok.
- And standard functions like: adding users stories to projects, add estimations, prioritizing, start sprints etc.

The most promising project which I found was https://leantime.io/ but it lacks the first feature I listed.

Answer (score 2):

Mine and my team's favorite alternative to Jira is [Linear](https://linear.app), at fact, it has a few integrations compared to Jira but it's way more lightweight and comfortable to be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still on the lookout, [Teamhood](https://teamhood.com) could be another option. As it allows you to oversee all projects in one portfolio view. And if you are running a smaller team, Timeline or Workload view in Teamhood could do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that's a tough feature for something that's not feature cluttered like Jira.  I'd recommend going with a standard bargain product like [Scrumfast.com](https://www.scrumfast.com), creating a "small customer" project, and simply using epics to link particular small customers.