# Open-source, self-hosted Jira-style ticketing

Tags: open-source, project-management, self-hosted, task-management

I'm looking for a ticket-based, agile-style task management software similar to Jira.

Required features:

- Server-client model. I intend to deploy this on my home server for my entire family to use.
- Multiple user accounts. I want to be able to create tickets and assign them to my wife, and vice versa. There should be proper access control, so that people without an account cannot see anything (without me having to add auth myself).
- Agile-style ticket paradigm. It must support:

  - Story points
  - Sprints
  - Priorities
  - Epics
  - Some form of tagging (eg. Jira components)
  - Statuses such as backlog, in progress, in review, done (Jira supports defining custom statuses which would be ideal)
- Completely free and open source
- Self-hosted

Nice to have:

- Good handling of due dates. Even though fundamentally agile goes by sprints not dates, I'd like the software to be able to remind me that the "Pay rent" ticket is due in X days, for instance
- Various metrics like burndown charts. Since this is for personal task management, it doesn't have to be too advanced, but I'd like to have some basic metrics like velocity so I can have an idea how long things take
- An easy to use API so I can plug missing functionality with my own software
- Automatically creating and assigning certain tickets (eg. "pay rent") - although I can write my own program for this if there's a decent API
- Android and iOS clients (a mobile-friendly web UI is good enough)
- A "print tickets" function like Jira has
- Simple database format so that I can migrate my data out if I decide to use something else later
- Existing docker image of the server

---

Note that:

- I am aware of *Getting Things Done* and software designed for it; while it has similarities to Jira GTD is different from what I'm looking for
- I am aware of (and use) taskwarrior and its ecosystem (eg. tasks), however it doesn't fulfill my requirements
- I am aware that Agile software development is arguably not suitable for personal organization; IMO this is a moot point for the purposes of this question

Comment: Maybe have a look at this question and their answers: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/75096/agile-scrum-project-management-like-jira-but-simpeler